# JsTestDriver, name of the test function

Tags: javascript, js-test-driver

Is there any restrictions on the name of the test function?

When I write the following as `testA()` and `testB()`, both of them will be implemented.

```
AjaxCreateTest = TestCase("AjaxCreateTest");  
AjaxCreateTest.prototype.testA = function(){};  
AjaxCreateTest.prototype.testb = function(){};
```

But if I change the name from "testB" to "AjaxCreateT", just `testA()` will be implemented. So weird. Could someone help?

Answer (score 3):

JsTestDriver only executes methods that start with the prefix "test". This is a naming convention to enable you to write helper methods on the same object that aren't executed as tests.

There are also two reserved method names `setUp` and `tearDown`, which will be executed before  and after each test respectively.

You can even use spaces in your test names, which makes your tests nicely readable, for example:

```
TestCase("AjaxCreateTest", {
    setUp : function() {
        this.subject = new MyAjaxCode();
        this.stubXHR();
    },

    tearDown : function() {
        this.restoreXHR();
    },

    stubXHR : function() {
        // stub global objects to intercept Ajax calls
    },

    restoreXHR : function() {
        // restore global state
    },

    "test should say hi" : function() {
        assertEquals("Hi", this.subject.sayHi());
    }
}
```

In the example above there's only one test, the rest are helper methods.

I can recommend [Sinon.JS](http://sinonjs.org/) for helping you stub your Ajax calls (see "Fake XHR") and for further examples.